# Python Sklearn Neural Network Classifier Iteration and Loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I was trying to implement a paper I read. Basically it uses 3 neural network classifiers with different parameter to work on the same loan default data with 9 different training-to-testing ratios.

In order to find best parameter, we use following criterion, when(1) `max_iteration=25000` 
and (2) Loss value is less than 0.008, we measure the accuracy value, and pick the best.

However, when I try to use python `sklearnsklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier` to finish this, I met a problem. When the training-to-test ratio increases, the iterating time the program runs drops dramatically. In the mean while, the loss value increases,

**Classifier Performance Table**.

[image]

This is clearly not what I want, the iterating number should keep rising to 25000 before stop.

This is how I defined classifer:

```
clf1= MLPClassifier(activation='relu',solver='sgd',early_stopping=False,alpha=1e-5,max_iter=25000,\
                hidden_layer_sizes=(18),momentum=0.7,learning_rate_init=0.0081,tol=0,random_state=3)
clf2= MLPClassifier(activation='relu',early_stopping=False,solver='sgd',alpha=1e-5,max_iter=25000,\
                hidden_layer_sizes=(23),momentum=0.69,learning_rate_init=0.0095,tol=0,random_state=3)
clf3= MLPClassifier(activation='relu',early_stopping=False,solver='sgd',alpha=1e-5,max_iter=25000,\
                hidden_layer_sizes=(27),momentum=0.79,learning_rate_init=0.0075,tol=0,random_state=3)
```

As you can see, I already set `Tolerance=0`, so that every time when we iterate, it could surely decrease the loss. And I had tried other value, but still, the iterate number is way smaller than I expected.

Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: Try setting `learning_rate='adaptive'` in each.

Comment: @VivekKumar Tried, the result improved, but still far from expected. The iterating time increases to about 500 times for the last few, and 1000 times for the middle few, far from 25000